# Main_menu Google Analytics Event Tracking

Tags: google-analytics

I have been asked to insert a google tracking code to all of my main_menu Links

```
<a href="/something" onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Menu', 'link-name', 'Click']);"\ >link-name</a>
```

I try to found a module but i couldn't found how to use it to accomplish this task.
https://drupal.org/project/google_analytics_et

I thought i can use a hook_menu but i need some help..

Drupal 7

Comment: Have you ever tried to enable the example module from here http://drupalcode.org/project/google_analytics_et.git/tree/69135bf:/google_analytics_et_example. I think you just enable that and it will apply google analytic for all selector like **#main-menu li a**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do that I was using [Menu attributes](https://drupal.org/project/menu_attributes) module with [Onclick Event](https://drupal.org/node/1923740) patch. Simply install it, apply patch, enable module and you will be able to add onclick code to menu elements via GUI.

Comment: It worked like a charm!!!!! One small thing because i have 50+ menu items is a way to make it more automatic because the only think it changes is the menu item name

Comment: @Drupalizeme post that as a comment in patch's issue? Should be easy enough. Or you can access link's name in javascript itself (if I get what you mean). I know seeding it is painful, but then you probably will not need to repeat it that many times. And of course I want to see alternative answers. Easier, more automated way should exist.

Answer (score 0):

You can also achieve this with hook_menu() and a preg_replace:

```
    /**
     * Implements theme_menu_tree__MENU_NAME.
     */
    function mytheme_menu_tree__menu_menuname($variables) {
      $variables['tree'] = preg_replace("@<a(.+)>(.+)</a>@", "<a $1 onclick=\"ga('send', 'event', 'Menu', 'click', '$2');\">$2</a>", $variables['tree']);
      return $variables['tree'];
    }
```